# Conditional hook

Tags: hooks

Is it possible to have a conditional hook in my child theme function.php? This is because I only want a certain hook to execute when a certain criteria exists.

I have tried doing the following code but it doesn't work

```
<?php
function check_product_in_cart() {

    global $woocommerce;
    $box_found = false;
    $voucher_found = false;
    $other_products_found = false;

    //start of the loop that fetches the cart items
    foreach($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $_product = $values['data'];
        $terms = get_the_terms( $_product->id, 'product_cat' );

        // second level loop search, in case some items have several categories
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            $_categoryid = $term->term_id;

            //check if BOX product category is in card
            if ( $_categoryid === 103 ) {
                //category is in cart!
                $box_found = true;
            } elseif ( $_categoryid === 106 ) { //check if VOUCHER product category is in card
                //category is in cart!
                $voucher_found = true;
            }else{
                $other_products_found = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return array($box_found, $voucher_found, $other_products_found);
}

remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_customer_details', array( $wc_checkout_add_ons->admin, 'render_add_ons' ) );
function edit_position_of_checkout_addons(){
    list($box_found, $voucher_found, $other_products_found) = check_product_in_cart();
    if(!$voucher_found){
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', array( $wc_checkout_add_ons->admin, 'render_add_ons' ) );
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_after_customer_details', 'edit_position_of_checkout_addons');
?>
```

Comment: where do you set `$product_found`? what action is it all hooked to?

Comment: check edits. I didnt hook it to anything, rather i want the hook to be execute conditionally.

Comment: the likely issue is that the code that does the conditional hooking runs way too early. functions.php is loaded before the init hook, which is where most plugins initialize their state, you're probably trying to remove actions which haven't been added yet. there should almost never be code just sitting in functions.php not hooked to an action. refer to the [action reference in codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) to see the order things are executed.

Comment: please see edit. unfortunately, it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

Where are you putting this code?
Probably this code is not being executed.

you should wrap everything in a function and trigger it with the wp_head hook...

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_head', 'woocommerce_conditional_hook');
function woocommerce_conditional_hook(){
    function check_product_in_cart() {

        global $woocommerce;
        $box_found = false;
        $voucher_found = false;
        $other_products_found = false;

    //start of the loop that fetches the cart items
        foreach($woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
            $_product = $values['data'];
            $terms = get_the_terms( $_product->id, 'product_cat' );

        // second level loop search, in case some items have several categories
            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                $_categoryid = $term->term_id;

            //check if BOX product category is in card
                if ( $_categoryid === 103 ) {
                //category is in cart!
                    $box_found = true;
            } elseif ( $_categoryid === 106 ) { //check if VOUCHER product category is in card
                //category is in cart!
                $voucher_found = true;
            }else{
                $other_products_found = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return array($box_found, $voucher_found, $other_products_found);
}

    list($box_found, $voucher_found, $other_products_found) = check_product_in_cart();
    if(!$voucher_found){
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_customer_details', array( $wc_checkout_add_ons->admin, 'render_add_ons' ) );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', array( $wc_checkout_add_ons->admin, 'render_add_ons' ) );
    }else{
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', array( $wc_checkout_add_ons->admin, 'render_add_ons' ) );
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: i have tried your method, but it does not work.As a test i have did the following, but still not working. `function edit_position_of_checkout_addons(){
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', array( $wc_checkout_add_ons->admin, 'render_add_ons' ) );
}
add_action('wp_head', 'edit_position_of_checkout_addons', 999);`

Comment: If the OP is putting it in functions.php in the active theme it will be executed on every page load.

Comment: what is OP? So does it mean i have to add a conditional tag such that it only appear on the page that i want it to appear at?

Comment: Are you debuging? make echo inside the functions to check if the functions are being called...